# display tagged posts AND custom posts in featured section

Tags: php, wordpress

In a homepage featured section I would like to display the 7 latest posts that are either regular posts tagged with tag id#50 OR custom type posts with post-type sp_events.

This isn't working. Presumably because tag__in is filtering out the untagged custom type posts. My php is so bad I can't see how to correct this.

```
    query_posts(
        array(
            'tag__in' => array(50),
            'showposts' => '7',
            'post_type' => array('post', 'sp_events')
        )
    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken (which I most certainly may be), you can't do a query like you're trying to do with Wordpress's built in functions.

What you can do is in your functions.php file (where one stores the theme's custom functions) having a function which takes an array of argument arrays and loops through them with every pass adding the returned posts to an array. I think [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) would be the best function to use for this since it returns the posts in an array instead of needing the Loop.

```
function query_posts_multiple($arrArgs)
{
  if (!is_array($arrArgs)) return false; // Prevents warnings and fatal errors.
  $posts = array();

  foreach ($arrArgs as $args)
  {
    $posts = array_merge($posts, get_posts($args));
  }

  return $posts;
}
```

For the args array, here's an example:

```
$args = array();
$args[] = array(
  'numberposts'     => 7,
  'tag'             => "50",
);
```

You would just use a foreach() loop in your theme. You would access the data using a $post->*column* fashion.

```
$posts = get_posts_multiple($args);
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
  // call all the $post->COLUMNs your heart desires
}
unset($posts); // Delete that variable just to be safe.
```

To limit the number of posts, just keep count and stop the loop when you reach a certain number. To randomize your array, you can use [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

This is probably a very, very dirty way of doing this, blame it on my extreme tiredness...

Logan

Comment: Thanks Logan. This pushes me way out of my limited php comfort zone. A friend confirms that your suggestion is indeed rather dirty ;)

I am astonished that it is not possible to call up custom posts and filtered 'regular' posts in the same section. Seems so basic.

Comment: I agree. The query to actually pull the posts is rather simple but why Wordpress decided to leave out such functionality is beyond me. They are, however, query conscious in there design and try to limit the number of queries to the database, so maybe that's why. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. And the solution is dead simple: instead of trying to make the filter apply only to the 'regular' posts, let the tag apply to the custom post type posts as well. I didn't realize the tags would share across post types.

I just added the following to functions.php and tagged the custom post type posts:

```
add_action('init', 'add_taxonomy_objects');

function add_taxonomy_objects() {
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'sp_events');
}'
```